# One dimensional boundary value problems showing interesting behaviour

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

I want to show some users of a piece of software some solutions of one-dimension boundary value problems (can also be initial value problems). I'm after a collection of problems whose solutions are very interesting or the BVP are of a particularly interesting nature.  The problems can be linear or non-linear. Does anyone have any suggests?

Comment: Wiki-ized: this is a question looking for examples.

Comment: What do you mean by 1D BVP? Is it only ODEs or PDEs in 1D space + time that you are talking about? In the latter case, it is clearer to call them *initial-boundary value problems*.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/mat463/ODEBook/Book/BVPs.pdf)(site about boundary value problems) should be useful. Some of the interesting boundary value problems they list are the following:

- Heat Equation
- Wave Equation
- Laplace Equation
- Poisson Equation
- Schrodigner's Equation

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the initial value problem, a large class of interesting 1-dimensional questions arise from studying various approximations to [surface waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_wave) starting from fundamental equations of fluid dynamics.

The [Korteweg-de Vries equation and its cousins gKdV and mKdV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation) all lead to demonstrations of a competition between cohesive self-interaction that leads to soliton formation, and dispersive wave-like phenomenon.

(What is especially interesting is to look at the purely dispersive part of the KdV equation 
$$ \partial_t \phi + \partial_x^3 \phi = 0 $$
and the purely transport part of the equation
$$ \partial_t \phi + \phi\partial_x\phi = 0 $$
and note their characteristic behaviours. Then compare it against various different initial data for the KdV equation.)

You can also consider looking at the [Benjamin-Bona-Mahony equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin%E2%80%93Bona%E2%80%93Mahony_equation), which shows off some long wavelength behaviour (in constrast to the KdV solitons, which tends to be more spatially concentrated).